# Correlating two skeletized images : Python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image 
from skimage import morphology
from scipy import signal

img = cv2.imread('thin.jpg',0)
img1 = cv2.imread('thin1.jpg',0)
cv2.imshow('image1',img)
cv2.imshow('image2',img1)
ret,img = cv2.threshold(img,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
ret,img1 = cv2.threshold(img1,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
size = np.size(img)
size1 = np.size(img1)
skel = np.zeros(img.shape,np.uint8)
skel1 = np.zeros(img1.shape,np.uint8)
element = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_CROSS,(3,3))
img = 255 - img
img1 = 255 - img1
img = cv2.dilate(img,element,iterations=8)
img1 = cv2.dilate(img1,element,iterations=8)

done = False

while(not done):
eroded = cv2.erode(img,element)
eroded1 = cv2.erode(img1,element)
temp = cv2.dilate(eroded,element)
temp1 = cv2.dilate(eroded1,element)
temp = cv2.subtract(img,temp)
temp1 = cv2.subtract(img1,temp1)
skel = cv2.bitwise_or(skel,temp)
skel1 = cv2.bitwise_or(skel1,temp1)
img = eroded.copy()
img1 = eroded1.copy()

zeros = size - cv2.countNonZero(img)
if zeros==size:
    done = True
 cv2.imshow('IMAGE',skel)
 cv2.imshow('TEMPLATE',skel1)
 cv2.imwrite("image.jpg",skel)
 if cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

This is the code that i tried to convert two grayscale image to two skeletized image using the method of binarization and thinning and the result is also obtained. Now with these two skeletized image , i want to do a comparison to see whether they match or not. How can i correlate each other? Do we need to convert this skeletized into 2d array? Can anyone suggest any solution. Thanks in advance.

[image: template]
[image: Query]

Comment: This link may help you: [Template Matching](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_template_matching/py_template_matching.html)

Comment: Thanks Huan but i guess template matching is used to find an object in a given image. What i need is to compare two images and find whether they are matching or not.

Comment: This function does the image correlation which is a common algorithm in image processing.  If these two images have the same size, the value returned by this function will be one point (It's up to the module you use. sometimes it will return the full size image, then you can use the value at the central point.) You can read the value as the correlation coefficient. But it's just a method you can try, maybe here are some better methods.

Comment: are both images/objects in the same scale and orientation? can you post additonal images? one (non-trivial) where the comparison should succeed and one (non-trivial) where the comparison should fail, if possible.

Comment: @Micka these images are of same size, ther can be a shift in this image, since they are not taken on same time. i need to match the pattern of the image. As you have asked me , trivial and non trivial images are attached

Comment: @ANUSHADEVI first two images are identical? with non-trivial example I meant that there might be an image that should match the query image but isn't identical. If you are only intereseted in identical images, image difference would be a good measure. Without knowing real sample images, I would say you can try chamfer matching.

Comment: @Micka first two images are the same images, which should be matched perfectly and the third one should not match with the frst one (first one is the reference image). But each time when i run the program there will be two different sets of images. I have read that in this cases the conventional method is correlation. But if the image pattern are similar with a slight shift in the image, will the correlation work?

Comment: that's why I asked for two "similar" but non-identical (because identical images are trivial to mach) images, which SHOULD be matched by your algorithm in addition to the third image (which is ok) ;) the whole task depends on what you mean by "similarity" (which probably is task/domain dependent). That's what it all is about.

Comment: :-) now i got what you asked for. Just now took this two image at two different time. They are similar and now the task is to match them :-(

Answer (score 0):

Binary images are already represented as 2D numpy arrays.

This is a complex problem. You can do this by reshaping the images to two vectors (assuming they are exactly the same size), and then calculating the correlation coefficient:

```
np.corrcoef(img.reshape(-1), img1.reshape(-1))
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways you can compare the images to see if they match.  The simplest is to do a pixelwise subtraction to create a new image and then sum the pixels in the new image.  If they sum to zero you have an exact match.  The larger the sum the worse the match.

You will however have a problem using most comparison techniques on a skeletonized image.  You take the image and reduce it to skinny little lines that are unlikely to overlap for images that only deviate from each other by a little bit.

With skeletonized images you often need to compare features.  For example, identify the points of intersection of the skeleton, and use the location of those points for comparing images.  In your sample image you might be able to extract the lines (I see three major ones) and then compare images based on the location of the lines.

Comment: thanks denver for the information...one doubt, if this is an iterative process like each time you run the program you need to compare different sets of images,will this work? each time can we identify the pattern of the images and compare with the other image?

Comment: @ANUSHADEVI I don't see why not.  You can improve efficiency by storing the feature set if you plan on comparing the image again down the road.

Comment: What if each time the image taken is a shifted one compared to the template image? About the point of intersection, its not necessary that everytime you take a image, you will find a intersection point. So there has to be a way that can help me in identifing similar images

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your question.  If you know something about the shift ahead of time, you should certainly take advantage of it.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution would be to correlate (or subtract) the *blurred* version of each skeletonized image with one another.

That way, the unavoidable little offsets between skeleton lines wouldn't have such a negative impact on the outcome as if you subtracted the skeletons directly (since the skeleton lines would most probably not overlay exactly over one another).

I'm assuming here that the original images weren't similar to each other in the first place, otherwise you wouldn't need to skeletonize them, right?

Comment: Since the images are takes at two different times, there can be a shift in images.If we need to match the two images based on the pattern of these lines, how this blurring will help out. For example: if i want to compare first and third image, how can i make sure that the pattern of lines are not same ? Am not at an expert and so numerous questions are popping out.:-)

Comment: Well, if these images come from video frames or sequential photos, then you'll need far more complex algorithms than binary skeletonization, I think. Perhaps you should ask another question going up one level: "how can I identify corresponding features on similar photos taken from slightly different perspective", or something like that. Hope this helps!